# How to install ralink rt3090 driver?

Tags: drivers, ralink

I have searched all over the internet and still cannot found the solution……. Can you guys try to teach me on how to install ralink rt3090 driver?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].